# Ruby BCrypt salting/hashing seems ... wrong?

Tags: ruby, authentication, passwords, bcrypt, salt

I've been creating salted passwords in a ruby app what I thought was the standard way:

```
password_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
password_hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(params[:pword], password_salt)
```

But on examining a test case, it looks like the salt is just being prepended to the hashed password:

[image: Fishy looking screencap of user table.]

Now, as I understand the point of salt, it's supposed to be concatenated onto the password BEFORE hashing, to push the password out of the size range that any pre-computed lookup-table, rainbow-table, etc.. could ever include. The point is, if someone gets your user database, they still can't crack the passwords using a lookup table. If the salt is prepended onto the password AFTER the hashing, and the hacker has downloaded the user table, it's not doing anything to secure the passwords. The hacker can just clip the salt off the front, get the original hash back, and then run a rainbow table on the hashes as if they were never salted.

Is this as much of a salt-fail as it appears to be? Is the problem in my code? Or is this Working As Expected And Secure for reasons I need to read up on? (Link, please.)

Answer (score 4):

1) Salt is necessary for verification, and thus must be stored alongside the hashed cyphertext. Whether it's two fields in a database or one smushed-together string, is immaterial.

2) One salt = one rainbow table. Sure, attacker could generate a new rainbow table for your salt; however, since time to build a rainbow table is basically equivalent to time to try all passwords the rainbow table is to cover, it is not a weakness as long as you don't reuse salts.

---

The use case for rainbow tables is it allows you to compute it *once*, then quickly test multiple passwords. A rainbow table typically covers all the passwords up to certain length, or at least with some restriction (e.g. with certain alphabet, or using a certain vocab list). Let's say you have a rainbow table that covers all the passwords up to 8 characters. So if someone has password "password", rainbow table will know what its hashed form would be (e.g. "WASSPORD" - using caps for cyphertext and lowercase for plaintext for readability of the example), and you can look up "WASSPORD" in the rainbow table and see the password is "password" extremely quickly.

However, say you have salt "peanuts". The password becomes "peanutspassword", and if you then encrypt it, lets say you get "WASSUPMYCRACKER". Ruby would print "peanutsWASSUPMYCRACKER" as the salted hash. At verification time, you separate "peanutsWASSUPMYCRACKER" into "peanuts" (salt) and "WASSUPMYCRACKER" (hash); append "peanuts" to the user's input of "password" to form "peanutspassword", and encrypt it again - you get "WASSUPMYCRACKER", which is a match, and the user is logged in. However, note that "peanutspassword" is longer than 8 characters, and will not be in the up-to-8-characters rainbow table.

Now, you can generate a "peanuts" rainbow table, by taking the same dictionary as the original rainbow table, prepending "peanuts", and encrypting it, but it would typically take longer than just brute-forcing the password ("peanuts"+"a"? "peanuts"+"aardvark"?...) because, at least when you brute-force, you would stop when you find the correct password.

However, if you knew that a certain application always used "peanuts" as its salt, you could make a "peanuts" rainbow table, and that application is toast, and its owners in a real jam.

**tl;dr:** Salt can be public; it just can't be reused.

---

**EDIT:** You seem to be under the impression that Ruby just pastes salt onto the hash of the unsalted plaintext. If it did that, then one would expect that for the same plaintext, the result's hind end (the cyphertext) would be the same, no matter the salt. It is easy to see that's not how it works:

```
3.times { puts BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret("password", BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt) }
# $2a$10$jxUToaac5UUzVRH9SnllKe52W1JMLu5tm0LwyrZ4x4e75O1FCn9Ea
# $2a$10$oBs3TyhgR/r12.cz2kdzh.O9WHVZifDPqTEg0.hGOMn7Befv.8hSy
# $2a$10$8rfQA5nzCZ74DwNrmhAhdOmoQOVhJnBfh0ikiOB0W7ZptwsLPGUwi
```

As the salt changes, the cyphertext *also* changes. Thus, you can't "just clip the salt off the front, get the original hash back, and then run a rainbow table on the hashes as if they were never salted."

Comment: Just to sum it up, BCrypt uses the salt to calculate the hash, and then adds the salt plaintext to the already calculated hash. This is necessary so that the verification method can extract it form there and use the same salt for verification.

Comment: Thanks, yes. I had understood it was my responsibility to store the hash myself, and apply it when decrypting the password. And if that was how it was done, then why would a second copy be prepended to the front of the final value? The explanation "because something's wrong" was what I came to, rather than "because you aren't actually responsible for storing the hash". The web documentation for BCrypt::Engine didn't enlighten me, either.

Comment: There is no decrypting. We’re talking about hashing, which is strictly one-way; so instead of decryption there’s verification. But yeah, salt has been stored with hashes since forever (I seem to remember old `crypt` prepending its puny 2-character password some 25-30 years ago...

Comment: Derp, salt, not password.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Problem in Python:

```
passw = "qay123"
salt = bcrypt.gensalt(14)
hashedpw = bcrypt.hashpw(passw, salt)
print salt
print hashedpw
```

Output:

```
$2b$14$fG3IoYLeIaf6gxZTHVR7eO  <--- salt
$2b$14$fG3IoYLeIaf6gxZTHVR7eOVOC08a77IDOiu4At4FKKecw1xBYKXyG <-- salt + hashedpw
```

So, the `hashpw`-function just concatenates the salt value with the hash value which is insecure, because the hacker can split salt+hashpw at position 30
and so eliminates the salt.

For rainbow-tables the hacker must be able to read the hashes, so the cutting isn't a problem. The only problem he could have, would be when the length of the salt would vary.

My thought is that you follow your own thought and use bscrypt as seemingly not intended.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately, this is not correct. BCrypt for python works the same as in ruby. As explain in Amadan's answer, the result of running the hashpw is not `salt+hash(passw)`, but rather `salt+hash(salt+pw)`. Running your code multiple times without changing the password shows that clearly :) The length of the salt is actually specified in there, as the `$14$` (`$` are delimiters, and the `2b`/`2a` is which bcrypt version was used)